# HTML Video not filling parent div

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I want a HTML video tag to fill my card. Like this:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-title>Ion Videp</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video #video controls="controls" class="video" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="../../../assets/push-ups.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
</ion-card>
```

But the Video just keeps the original size.

I tried these css styles:

```
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.video {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But it still won't work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about the iconic-framework but the `.video` declaration in your css does not target anything in your mark up since none of the elements have a class of  `video`. Try applying the video class to the video element.

Comment: @Daniel yep, I  forgot to attach the class after testing a lot of thing. But when attaching the class the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

```
.video {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100vw; /* you can changes size*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation makes the answer more useful.

Comment: That doesn't work either. How is it suppose to work anyways, you set the with to 100% of the screen, right? I only want the video to fill a div. Appreciate the help though.